# open-source files into flashable .img ?? How?

Tags: android, kernel

I am **using Windows** (I don't know how to do it...  I don't have linux, so I can't do it myself) and I need help, to convert this file (Alcatel) - http://sourceforge.net/projects/alcatel/files/OT_5020D_20130606.tar.xz/download into a flashable image. If anyone can help me, or can compile it, I will be glad.

P.S. This is the content of that ZIP file  - https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nt4fB.png (my PHONE'S system files are lost, and can't do anything, just frozen on startup ALCATEL message screen. ALCATEL support told me to compile the flashable image from the link I provided above.)

Comment: can you extract it and see what inside? if it is a zip file inside, open the zip file and show us what is inside.

Comment: The zip file does not look like a flashable image. However you can still give it a try http://theunlockr.com/2013/12/23/flash-custom-recovery-alcatel-one-touch-mpop-ot-5020x/

Comment: @Krypton thanks a million, it was very good tutorial... but my PHONE'S system files are lost, and cant do , just frozen on startup ALCATEL message screen. ALCATEL support told me to compile the flashable image from the above link i have provided.

Comment: How is this a SO question, when it clearly has nothing to do with programming?

Answer (score 1):

If the only problem is that you cannot install Linux as your main operating system, put the Linux into virtual machine and do the work there.

You can use some free virtual machine like [Oracle Virtual Box](https://www.virtualbox.org/), for instance that only takes minutes to set up. You will get the internal IP address, visible from your workstation only, that is enough for your task. You can use usual SSH and SFTP to communicate with it and the virtual machine itself will provide shell access for the initial setup. If necessary, it is also possible to configure such a virtual machine to connect the outside Internet.

Comment: thanks, but i cant do the setups and manual KERNEL compilation.. I am noob, i dont know the coding of linnux commands and etc... I need someone's help, to do it in few clicks (who knows already)

Comment: You do not need to compile the kernel just to install Linux. And, if you need to compile the kernel later, Windows are user friendly in many things but compiling Linux kernel ... is unlikely to be between these ....

Answer (score 1):

As said from my comment, you can try flashing the custom recovery on to the phone first http://theunlockr.com/2013/12/23/flash-custom-recovery-alcatel-one-touch-mpop-ot-5020x/

With the custom recovery, you can try to flash the zip file that you extracted from the .tar.xz file. If you are unable to flash the zip file, I suggest you to download a CyanogenMod zip file from here http://forum.xda-developers.com/general/general/rom-mod-alcatel-5020-t3060346/post59584683#post59584683 and see what is inside. And then you tailor your zip file's structure accordingly.

Btw, your zip file is not a kernel. From the size, I believe it should be the entire ROM. Kernel should be less than 10MB AFAIK.

Answer (score 0):

Your file above is likely your android operating system, not your kernel. I recently flash a new kernel to my Samsung Galaxy Centura, it was less than 20mb. I don't know what you did to your phone, but you may not need to do anything with the kernel. You said your system files were missing, so if you could get someone to convert you file to a flashable zip then you could probably fix your phone.

Comment: This is a bit late- how did you flash "only the kernel" to your android device?

Answer (score 0):

What you essentially need is a ROM image for your phone model. I guess building it from sources is the hardest way to get it, and probably will take a lot of time for you to figure out how to do it properly(like weeks,and there is big chance to kill your phone for good by flashing bad ROM). So I suggest to find already compiled ROM for your phone with stock or some custom firmware (I suggest to check if there is CyanogenMod port for your phone) and flash this.